# How to avoid unintentional changing a global variable when using it as a local variable (inside a function)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, global-variables

**Problem:**

I am using a function that takes a (global) variable as an input, then performs operations on that variable (locally), and then returns that same variable. I do only want the variable to change locally, but instead my function is changing the global variable as well.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
data = {'A' : [1,2,3],
        'B' : [4,5,6],
        'C' : [7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def func(df):
    df['D'] = df['A'] * df['B'] / df['C']
    return df

func(df) # running function, without assigning it to original variable

print(df)
```

**Returns:**

Running the code shows that the original dataframe has been changed and a column was added.

```
   A  B  C   D
0  1  4  7  12
1  2  5  8  15
2  3  6  9  18
```

**Expected behaviour:**

My intention is to run the function without adding the column to the global variable, only add it locally within the function.

```
    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

**Set-up:**

- Python 3.7
- Pandas 0.25.3
- Windows 10

Comment: `df` is a local variable, but it refers to the same object as the global variable `data`. *All* function arguments behave this way. The general rule is: don't use a mutating method on a function argument unless you intend to modify the object.

Comment: or do `ret = df.copy()` and work with the `ret` dataframe in your function.

Comment: You need to make your own local copy of `df` if you intend to add a new column temporarily, or (if other threads using the data frame aren't a concern) you can remove the new column with `del df['D']` before returning.

Comment: Don't focus on the variables - variables are just ways to refer to objects, and **objects** are what really matter in a Python program.

Comment: Also see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make a local copy:

```
def func(d):
    df = d.copy()
    df['D'] = df['A'] * df['B'] / df['C']
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!

I'm still wondering, why doesn't my code behave as I expected?

Comment: Because passing parameters (and in fact all assigments) in Python is done by reference. When you do `x = y`, you're not copying the value of `y `- instead, you're making `x` refer to the same object as `y` does. Therefore `df` in your function refers to the same object the actual parameter (which you somewhat unfortunately also named `df`) refers to,

Comment: Okay, so to make sure I understand correctly, moving variables into a different namespace does not automatically create a copy of the variable into that new namespace. Thus changing the variable in one namespace (local) will also change the variable in the other namespace (global). Is that right?